# Pass validation errors in own control 

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I've got my own user control:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = StateValid, GroupName = GroupValidation)]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = StateInvalidFocused, GroupName = GroupValidation)]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = StateInvalidUnfocused, GroupName = GroupValidation)]
public class SearchTextBoxControl : TextBox
{
    // properties removed for brevity

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.BindingValidationError += (s, e) => UpdateValidationState();
        this.UpdateValidationState();
    }

    public const string GroupValidation = "ValidationStates";
    public const string StateValid = "Valid";
    public const string StateInvalidFocused = "InvalidFocused";
    public const string StateInvalidUnfocused = "InvalidUnfocused";

    private void UpdateValidationState()
    {
        var textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentTextBox");
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            VisualStateManager
                .GoToState(textBox as Control, 
                           Validation.GetErrors(this).Any() ? 
                               StateInvalidUnfocused : 
                               StateValid, 
                           true);
        }
    }
}
```

and XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="local:SearchTextBoxControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SearchTextBoxControl">
                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox x:Name="ContentTextBox"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                             Text="{TemplateBinding Text}">
                    </TextBox>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource BrowseButton}"
                            Command="{TemplateBinding Command}">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" />
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                        <Image  Source="../../Resources/Images/magnifier.png"
                                Style="{StaticResource BrowseButtonImage}" />
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What should I do to pass validation errors to the TextBox x:Name="ContentTextBox" validation service (I want the same validation error tooltip on my control text box)?
Kind regards!

Comment: Anyway - do you know answer? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, probably no.  In WPF, for something simple like this, I'd implement IDataErrorInfo, and do the ValidatesOnDataErrors thing.  But I'm not sure if that is supported in Silverlight, or when using visual states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement IDataErrorInfo Interface. It is available in ComponentModel Lib.

using System.ComponentModel;

public class SearchTextBoxControl : TextBox , IDataErrorInfo

{

```
    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    #endregion
    // Your Code
```

}

Comment: This is not exactly what I've looking for, but thanx :)